# oracle 11g resultSet how to get the table name

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g

I found there is some problem in `Oracle 11g` to get table name from interface`(ResultSet.getMetaData().getTableName(int column));`

It always show the empty string.

Is there something wrong for oracle database or jdbc driver? If the jdbc driver's problem , Can I get another jdbc driver to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code,ResultSet interface does not have getTableName http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: oops, I re-edit my post!

Comment: `getTableName()` is simply not implemented in the Oracle JDBC driver.

Comment: show the full code if possible?

Comment: It seems I walked into a death end. Thanks for all your help! By the way, I love mysql!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/datacc.htm#JJDBC28403) this is not supported:

> but does not implement the `getSchemaName` and `getTableName` methods because Oracle Database does not make this feasible

[Earlier Oracle drivers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/jdbc_drivers/oracle.html#wp1075290) did have this feature, but it needed to be enabled explicitly because of its performance implications. As far as I can tell from the documentation this is no longer available in more recent drivers.

Comment: Thank you verymuch! You save me a lot of time to work it out... I think I should by pass this issue. I have not enough reputation to vote you up! So sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the following http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html

Comment: seems helpless, i test by use of getCatalogName(int column); empty string returned also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
DatabaseMetaData  metadata = currentConnection.getMetaData();
String[] names = {"TABLE"}; 
ResultSet tables = metadata.getTables(null,"%", "%", names);
while (tables.next()) { 
  String tableName = tables.getString("TABLE_NAME"); 
  String tableSchema = tables.getString("TABLE_SCHEM");
}
ResultSet columns = metadata.getColumns(null, "%", tableName, "%");
while (columns.next()) { 
  String columnName = columns.getString("COLUMN_NAME"); 
  String datatype = columns.getString("TYPE_NAME"); 
  int datasize = columns.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE"); 
  int nullable = columns.getInt("NULLABLE");
}
```

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html#getTables_java_lang_String__java_lang_String__java_lang_String__java_lang_String___) for more info.

Comment: That is not a replacement for `ResultSetMetaData.getTableName()` - `getTableName()` should return the underlying table of a query column. `getTables()` won't help you find out to which table a query column belongs to.

Comment: Agreed. But as you mentioned, `getTableName()` is simply not implemented in the Oracle JDBC driver. This isn't efficient, but looping through the tables and their columns is probably the only way to do it. I hope someone posts a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

after running into this specifical issue face-first a few days ago, I finally came up with a solution that does the job. Of course it's neither pretty nor... well... anything, but it works.

Basically, I **check every table** in my database against the **columns** in the ResultSet.

I hope someone else can use this. Took me about a day to get this straight.

*Note: I use a CachedRowSet instead of a ResultSet, which doesn't require me to keep the database connection open the whole time.*

---

---

```
 private static String getTableNameByCols(ResultSetMetaData rsmd, DatabaseMetaData dbmd) throws SQLException{

    String errorString = "No matching table found for the given column Set";
    String ret = null, origColName, origDatatype, tableName; 
    String[] names = {"TABLE"}; 

    ResultSet tables = dbmd.getTables(null, username, "%", names);

    // get all the columns out of the rsmd and put them into an Array
    Integer numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    String[] origColNames = new String[numberOfColumns+1];
    String[] origColTypeNames = new String[numberOfColumns+1];

    for (int i=1; i<numberOfColumns+1; i++){
        origColNames[i] = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        origColTypeNames[i] = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i);
    }

    ResultSet columns = null;
    while (tables.next()) { 

        tableName = tables.getString("TABLE_NAME"); 
        columns = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
        CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(columns);

        Integer tablesNumberOfColumns = crs.size();

        int i = 1; 

        if (numberOfColumns.intValue() == tablesNumberOfColumns.intValue()){

            while (crs.next()) {

                origColName = origColNames[i];
                origDatatype = origColTypeNames[i];

                String colName = crs.getString(4); 
                String datatype = crs.getString(6); 
                //int datasize = columns.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE"); 
                //int nullable = columns.getInt("NULLABLE");
                if (origColName.equals(colName) && origDatatype.equals(datatype) ){
                    ret = tableName;
                } else {
                    ret = null; 
                }
                i += 1;

            } // looked at all the columns
            crs.close();

        }// same # of columns check over

        if (ret != null) {
            break;
        }

        columns.close();    
    }

    verify(ret, errorString);
    return ret; 
}
```

The surrounding method:

```
private static boolean updateLocalTable(ResultSet rs){

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
    DatabaseMetaData dbmd;
    String table_name;
    boolean ret = false; 
    try {
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
        table_name = getTableNameByCols(rsmd, dbmd);

        /* ... do stuff with it ... */

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        print("kablooey! \n" + e.getStackTrace());
    }

    return ret;
}
```